# Utilizar PyQt5 con Qgis 2.99 en Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

Deseo poder programar en Qdesigner, por ello instalo PyQt5, aplicaciones GIS, importando QGIS 2.99 en PyQt para poder hacer uso de Qgis

He leido bastante porque no logro hacer la importación de Qgis en python 3.5

> Sistema Operativo: Windows 7 - 64 bits

Archivos instalados

> python-3.5.4-amd64.exe
>
> PyQt5-5.6-gpl-Py3.5-Qt5.6.0-x64-2.exe
>
> QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.99.0-38-Setup-x86_64.exe

He leído por la web que necesito ejecutar desde la consola de python lo siguiente:

```
from qgis.core import *

import qgis.utils
```

Pero al intentar ejecutar la primera sentencia aparece el siguiente error:

> error no modelu named 'qgis'

---

Les cuento que ya agregue en el PATH de windows las url de python, de qgis, lo raro es que según lo que pude leer dentro de QGIS debería haber una carpeta python, pero al fijarme encontré 2 carpetas una de python 2.7 y otra de python 3.6. cuyas versiones las instalé pero las desinstalé para dejar definitivamente la version 3.5. QGIS 2.99 es lo último que instale.

Esta es una: C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.99\apps\Python27

Esta es la otra: C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.99\apps\Python36

Así mismo he agregado al path

C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.99\bin
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.99\lib

En conclusión lo que deseo hacer es poder programar en QDesigner que se instala con PyQT incorporando la libreria de QGIS

Comment: Estas haciendo una aplicación desktop usando las librerias de qgis o haciend un plugin para qgis?entiendo que es lo primero verdad?Como es eso de poder programar en QDesigner?Puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que estas haciendo?Una traza?algun screenshot?

Comment: Es que recién estoy tratando de integrar las herramientas. Lo que deseo hacer es realizar un desarrollo, hacer una aplicación incluyendo a QGIS, entiendo que la herramienta de programación es PyQt verdad? y dentro de PyQt tenes a QDesigner para diseñar los entornos gráficos. Bueno lo que deseo hacer es incorporar QGIS para poder realizar un sistema geográfico utilizando la API de QGIS. Es decir, NO quiero hacer un Plugins dentro de la herramienta, sino que lo que deseo es programar mi propia herramienta GIS utilizando las bondades de QGIS

Comment: Y justamente lo que no puedo hacer es meter a qgis dentro de PyQt. En la pregunta inicial está detallado el error GRACIAS

Comment: Mira esto https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102 y comprueba que tienes bien las variables de entorno,que es basicamente tu problema

Comment: Ah y otra cosa es que la version que emplea qgis 2.99 de python es la 3.6 no la 3.5

Comment: Gracias Francisco, pero el tema luego es que me funcione PyQT5 con python 3.6, porque no he encontrado la version de PyQT que me especifique python 3.6.